# Server-side ruby vs client-side js api speed/organization

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Say I have certain string attributes of an AR object, 'filename' and 'title' for instance, and the way I wish to dynamically fill in a select box on the front end is to ajax in the JSON representation of this object and either display the title attr as the select option's text if it exists, or use the filename attr as the select option's text if the title attr is blank. Now, should I be doing the this-else-that logic I just described on the server-side and returning it w/in my object's JSON representation as something like a 'display_name' attr, or should I be returning the vanilla as_json representation of the object w/ only the AR attrs included and let the js make the decision whether to display the title attr or the filename attr as the select option's text? From what I can tell, JS is much faster than ruby, but at the same time, it seems more maintainable to have this logic on the server-side. I'd also like to know, in general, is executing logic faster on the client side w/ js, or on the server-side w/ ruby? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have to worry about speed too much here - it's highly unlikely that you are really going to suffer from performance problems caused by if/else statements unless you're doing something wrong.

Instead, go for clarity and simplicity. In this case, that probably means rendering the pages on the server directly, unless the data is already in JSON for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to put logic where it belongs. If the logic is about presentation/rendering, then I would put it in your presentation layer. From your description, this seems to be your client-side JS.

I recommend you keep your APIs agnostic of how their data is rendered/presented as much as possible. This will allow you to change your views without having to also change the structure of the payload returned by the APIs.

In my experience, presentation layers tend to change more often than the underlying structure of the data they present.
I agree with the previous answer, I wouldn't worry about speed here, and go for clear separation of concerns.